# Loop com For Next em ASP clássico

Tags: data, asp

Preciso fazer um loop onde eu tenho o ano atual 2019, mais quero mostrar os próximos 10 anos a partir desta data usando um loop, com esse resultado ex:

```
2019
2020
2021
2022
2023
2024
2025
2026
2027
2028
2029
```

Sei que um loop básico seria assim :

```
For data = 1 To 12
   response.write( data + 1 & "<br />")
Next
```

Porém quero saber de uma maneira onde pega diretamente do `date`, pois assim conforme os anos forem passando as datas também iram mudar.

Obs.: em ASP clássico.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faça assim:

```
<%
for data = year(now) to year(now)+10
   response.write data &"<br>"
next
%>
```

O `year(now)` pega o ano atual.

O código acima irá imprimir:

```
2019
2020
2021
2022
2023
2024
2025
2026
2027
2028
2029
```